# How can I sort my search results? First the matches in the Title

Tags: search-results

I created a new searchresult page with a search result webpart. I already modified the search sorting in the webpart properties. When I search on "bra" I first got a result where the word "bra" is found in the content. The results below are matches in the Title. I would like to have the Title matches as first. What do I need to do?

This is the sort json value:

```
[{"name":"Titel","sorts":[{"p":"Filename","d":0}]},{"name":"Relevantie","sorts":[]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 search has [Ranking Models](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/7c8ddec1-c8ff-4a90-afae-387b27a653f1.aspx#Ranking_Models) which allows you to show most relevant data on top (for eg in your case Show **Title** matches on top).

Follow the below steps:

1. Configure the webpart properties and set sorting by **Rank**. Now the results will higher rank (or relevance) will be displayed on top.
2. Now you have to configure your search so that "**Title**" column has top rank than other columns.You can do that by any of following methods:

   a. [Query rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/7c8ddec1-c8ff-4a90-afae-387b27a653f1.aspx#Ranking_QueryRules)

   b. [Search schema](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/7c8ddec1-c8ff-4a90-afae-387b27a653f1.aspx#Ranking_Schema)

   c. [Create and use a custom ranking model](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/7c8ddec1-c8ff-4a90-afae-387b27a653f1.aspx#Ranking_CustomModel)

   Now if you are using OOTB Title column, it is by default having the top most rank score. So if you change the sort order to **Sort by Rank** (Step 1), it should show Title matches on the top.